# ModuleNotFoundError Cannot import from app.__init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I'm trying to setup a flask application which runs on Python 3.7.x. I've referenced many tutorials online but can't seem to resolve this ModuleNotFoundError and none of the stackoverflow questions are related.

Below is my project structure:

```
project/
    app/
        __init__.py
        api.py
        conf.py
        models.py
        schema.py
    orders-mgmt.toml
    requirements.txt
    README.md
```

```
# app/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from app.conf import load_from_toml
import logging
import os.path

if os.path.isfile('/opt/project/orders-mgmt.toml'):
    config = load_from_toml('/opt/project/orders-mgmt.toml')
else:
    config = load_from_toml()

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = config['mysql']['db_uri']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {
    'pool_recycle': 3000,
    'pool_pre_ping': True,
}
```

```
# app/api.py

from flask import jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import app, api, config #ERROR here
from app.models import Request
from app.schema import RequestSchema

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class TestGet(Resource):

    def get(self):
        return 'okay'


api.add_resource(TestGet, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

I'm getting the `ModuleNotFoundError` in `app/api.py` line `from app import app, api, config` when I run `python app/api.py`:

```
$ python app/api.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app, api, config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

May I know what is the issue here with my flask application?

Comment: Only package initialization code should go into `__init__.py`. Since you don't use `app` as a package, it should be empty or not even there.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular dependency issue
Your app will not work in such files structure
Remove logic from init module to another one OR you'll need to remove all absolute imports(imports for your own modules) and replace them with relative

### for `__init__` module

replace this line:

```py
from app.conf import load_from_toml
```

with

```py
from .conf import load_from_toml
```

### for `app` module

replace these lines:

```py
from app import app, api, config #ERROR here
from app.models import Request
from app.schema import RequestSchema
```

with

```py
from . import app, api, config
from .models import Request
from .schema import RequestSchema
```

Comment: I'm getting ```ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from '__main__'``` from line ```from . import app, api, config```

Comment: @kaiilim I suggest you to change the project structure. Remove all logic from `__init__` module and put into app/app.py module. Leave `__init__` module just blank